# Changing variables in a partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have the equation and function $$f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n) = 0,\qquad x_1 = g_1(y_1, y_2, y_3,...,y_m)$$ then what is $\frac {\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}$ in terms of $g_1$ and $y_i$?

Comment: The first thing that you list is not a function; it is an equation.  Implicitly, any of the $x_i$ can almost always be locally viewed as functions of the other $x_i$, but still, what you have written is not a function.

Comment: @alex yes, I've edited it now.

Comment: I guess my point is, why include the "$=0$"?  You are asking for a derivative of $f_1$, so that means you want to think of $f_1$ as having output that changes as input changes.  Yet if you have set $f_1(\ldots)$ equal to zero, then $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}$ is trivially equal to $0$.  I still don't know what you mean to ask, but I'm pretty sure that this is not it.

Comment: @alex $df_1=0$ doesn't imply $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} = 0$

Comment: I'm not sure what "$df_1$" means in this context , but put that aside.  If I defined $f(x)=0$ and asked you to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, what would you tell me?  The derivative a constant function is $0$.  That is exactly what is going on with your question the way it is currently worded.

Comment: @alex $f_1$ in my question is a function of more than one variable, so it's not the same as your example. $df_1$ is the total differential of $f_1$ from basic calculus

Comment: There's too much confusion to continue this way.  For example, if the total differential of $f$ is zero, it most certainly does imply that all of $f$'s partial derivatives are zero.  But if you are convinced otherwise, I'm not sure how I can change your mind.  I would suggest taking your question to a multivariable calculus instructor in person.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if that is what you need, 
but if you have a function of $n$ variables $f_{1}(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3},...,x_{n})$, where 
$x_{1} = g_{1}(y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3},...,y_{m})$, $x_{2} = g_{2}(y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3},...,y_{m}),\dots, x_{n} = g_{n}(y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3},...,y_{m})$  are also some functions of $m$ variables, then you can find partial derivatives of $f_{1}$ with respect to $y_{i},  i=\overline{1,n} $ using the formula:

$$\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y_{i}} = \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}\frac{\partial x_{1}}{\partial y_{i}} + \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}\frac{\partial x_{2}}{\partial y_{i}} + \ldots + \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{n}}\frac{\partial x_{n}}{\partial y_{i}} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{k}}\frac{\partial x_{k}}{\partial y_{i}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that you have a function of more than one variable.  Let's take the example of $f$, where:  $$f(x,y)=x^2-2xy+y^2-1$$  This function can take differing values as $x$ and $y$ vary.  And that means we have "interesting" derivatives we can study.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & =2x-2y\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} & =-2x+2y
\end{align*}

Sometimes, we will become interested in studying one of $f$'s level sets.  That means the set of all $(x,y)$ such that the output of $f$ is some constant level $k$.  In our example, we might consider $$f(x,y) = 0$$ and what we mean is the set of all $(x,y)$ where $$x^2-2xy+y^2-1=0$$ It doesn't really make sense to speak of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ anymore.  Our attention is focused on the curve with the equation $x^2-2xy+y^2-1=0$, and on that curve $f$ is identically $0$.  We might consider a small change in $x$, but the constraint will force a small change in $y$ so that together, the corresponding change in $f$ will be $0$.  So if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ means anything at all, it means the derivative of the zero function: $0$.

Of course nothing is stopping us from going back and working with the partial derivative computed earlier: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =2x-2y$.  And maybe that is what you intend in your question.  But then I ask why include the "$=0$" in your question at all?

Assuming that you would be interested in the partial derivative $2x-2y$ for this example, then the answer is just as Abramodj has said.  To keep this example going, suppose $x=g(s,t)=\sin(s)\cos(t)$.  Then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & = 2x-2y\\
&=2g(s,t)-2y\\
&=2\sin(s)\cos(t)-2y
\end{align*}

May I ask how this question arose?  It looks like a familiar issue that arises in a vector calculus course when you learn that on surfaces $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{F_x}{F_z}$.  But I might be mistaken.

Comment: The equation comes from minimising a function with constraints, using Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is just

$$ \frac {\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} $$

and the relation you ask is given by substituting $x_1$ in this expression with

$$ g_1(y_1, y_2, y_3,...,y_m) $$

Comment: Doesn't really help, but thanks anyay